# Game develop on android

Tags: android, game-engine

My computer stopped working recently. Is it still possible for me to develop games directly from my android device?

I have already tried playir, but decided I ideally want something more advanced than a drag-and-drop tool.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an app that allows you to write and compile native Android apps using Java and C/C++, just as you would within Android Studio or Eclipse on a PC.

The app is called AIDE: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en

There is nothing more advanced than writing actual code.

Comment: I really would like to know the reason for that down vote...